# Page no for sub report in BIRT Reporting tool

Tags: birt

I want to use page numbers for a sub report in Birt 4.2 but it shows only `1` for all pages.
I have used the `pageNumber` variable in the footer of master page.

It's working fine for single table reports, but for nested or sub reports (table inside table) it shows the number 1 for all pages in .pdf

Answer (score 0):

If the sub report is a different report file you could pass a variable with the page number to it from the first report.

If it is in the same file, verify that the page variable is in the master page and not in the standard report flow.

Consider reviewing https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/457987/ for more discussion of page numbers and tables.

Comment: It is in the same file. and I put PageNumer in master page itself.

Comment: It is in the same file. and I put pageNumer in master page itself not in actual report. ex : There is one table named Table1 and in first cell Table2 is inserted. Its working fine when I don't insert Table2 in First table. but for both tabel  it shows 1 for all pages. Is it requires grouping?

Comment: Can you make a sample file with this issue in it?